# Adobe Flash Developer License Cost

Tags: flash, adobe

I want to develop a flash application, I would like to know how do I go about buying a license to develop using flash and also if anyone has an idea as to what the cost is.

Answer (score 5):

You can create content for the FlashPlayer with a number of free (as in freedom) tools.

You can either use [ActionScript 3](http://macromedia.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/actionscript3_overview.html) and [MXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML) and compile it with the [Flex SDK](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK). For Windows I suggest [**FlashDevelop**](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) as an IDE. It will download the Flex SDK for you and you can start to code right away.

Another alternative is [Haxe](http://haxe.org). The Haxe compiler can target the FlashPlayer (and many other platforms). The aforementioned FlashDevelop also has excellent Haxe support.

There's also a line of commercial products from Adobe for flash development, which includes the designer-centric Adobe Flash Professional and Adobe Flash Catalyst, as well as the developer-centric Adobe Flash Builder. And there is quite a number of 3rd party tools, [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) being the most noteworthy for developers. Also a free version has become available recently.

Personally, I don't recommend any of the commercial tools I mentioned, but each of them has a 30 day evaluation period (or more), in which you can see for yourself. Typically these products have prices starting at 500 USD for commercial licences.